# Create a user friendly drop down while retaining original column value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to create a user friendly drop down using the following columns:

```
LNAME, FNAME, USERID
```

Here is my `SelectCommand`:

```
SELECT ISNULL(LNAME,'') + ', ' + ISNULL(FNAME,'') + ' (' + ISNULL(USERID,'') + ') ' AS FullName FROM USER ORDER BY FullName
```

The result is:

```
LNAME, FNAME (USERID)
```

This is what I want. I am trying to set the `DataValueField` to the `USERID` for use in `SelectedIndexChanged`. Right now it only works when `DataValueField` is set to `FullName`. I receive the following error when setting it to `USERID`:

> DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property
>   with the name 'USERID'.

I need to use the `USERID` for the next step. Is there a way to extract `USERID` from the alias in this `SELECT` statement?

Comment: Can you show us the code for your dropdownlist?

Comment: Opps, yes. I changed the terms to read more generic on here and missed that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your SQL to separate value and label (text)

```
SELECT
   USERID, -- what the user actually selects
   ISNULL(LNAME,'') + ', ' + ISNULL(FNAME,'') + ' (' + ISNULL(USERID,'') + ') '
           AS FullName --what user sees and appears to SELECT
FROM
   USER
ORDER BY
   FullName
```

Then you bind

- DataValueField to USERID
- DataTextField to Fullname

The [example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.dropdownlist.aspx) shows this: the value has no spaces eg "Dark Khaki" vs "DarkKhaki"

Comment: Thanks for the education. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your code it hard to give a definate answer, but I would recommend selecting the "user friendly" value as well as the UserID:

```
SELECT ISNULL(LNAME,'') + 
       ', ' + 
       ISNULL(FNAME,'') + 
       ' (' + 
       ISNULL(USERID,'') + 
       ') ' AS FullName,
       UserID
FROM USER ORDER BY FullName
```

Then specify UserId as the DataValueField.  Right now you aren't selecting UserId, so if you try to specify it as the DataValueField it will blow up.